# TraceListener does not output all traces

Tags: c#, trace, tracelistener

I've configured my WPF application with the following `TraceListener`

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
    <listeners>
      <add name="myListener" type="MyApp.RollTraceListener, MyApp" initializeData="myapplication.log" />
      <add name="listener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="application.log" />
    </listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

In `Release`, the TRACE constant is defined but I have not the same content in both files. What am I missing ?

```
public class RollTraceListener : System.Diagnostics.TraceListener
{
   string fileName;
   DateTime startDate;
   StreamWriter traceWriter; 

   public RollTraceListener(string fileName)
   {
      this.fileName = fileName;
      this.startDate = System.DateTime.Now;
      var stream = new FileStream(this.fileName, FileMode.Create);
      traceWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);
   }

   public override void Write(string value)
   {
      traceWriter.Write(value);
   }

   public override void WriteLine(string value)
   {
      traceWriter.WriteLine(value);
   }

   protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
   {
      if(disposing)
      {
         traceWriter.Flush();
         traceWriter.Close();
      }
   }
}
```

Typically, if I just write `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Hello World!");` the line is present in application.log but not in myapplication.log

Comment: Ok, I simply did the same but instead of configure it in the app.config, I declare the listener by code at startup, and flush/close the stream when exiting the application. It works fine.

Comment: Probably hasn't flushed yet. The RollTraceListener is going to be static, ie. live for the life of the AppDomain. Try flushing after each WriteLine.